# jQuery each() - return value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
i = 60;
i = $(this).find('li a').each(function(i) {
    w = $(this).text();
    $('#js').text(w);
    w = $('#js').width();
    if(w > i) {
        i = w;
    }
    return i;
});
```

It's wrong :-).
I have X strings (`$(this).find('li a')`). I want to get the length (px) of the longest one and save its length to variable `i` that I will use later in my code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't declare an `i` argument on the function you're giving `each`, don't return anything from the `each` function, and don't assign the result of `each` to `i`. Then it should work.

```
i = 60;
$(this).find('li a').each(function() {
    var w = $(this).text();
    $('#js').text(w);
    w = $('#js').width();
    if(w > i) {
        i = w;
    }
});
```

That way, the function you're passing into `each` is a closure over `i` and so can access and update it directly. By declaring `i` as an argument of the `each` callback, you were dealing with a different `i` on each iteration (the one that jQuery passes in, which is the index of the element in the set). And separately, the return value of `each` is the jQuery object on which you call it ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/)), which clearly isn't what you want.

More about closures, if you're not clear on them: *[Closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)*

In the code above, I also declared the `w` variable as local to the `each` callback, because I'm assuming you don't have a `w` variable outside of it you want updated and so were falling prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Comment: Also I think the `return i;` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @mridkash: You're right, I did that in the code I posted but forgot to mention it in the opening sentence.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that a baby penguin dies whenever the `var` keyword is omitted.

Comment: Also, returning false from the function stops the each, returning anything else is the equivalent of "continue."