# jQuery check all text inputs are disabled then continue

Tags: jquery

When a button is clicked a form gets sent via ajax but I would like firstly to check that all text inputs are disabled. I have tried the following but when an element is left enabled the console.log returns `done` which is not what should be happening.

When each `input[type=text]` are filled in correctly they get the attribute `disabled="disabled"`.

**jQuery**

```
$('.vacancy-submit').click(function(){
        var isValid = false;
        $("input[type=text]").each(function(){
            if ( $(this).is('[disabled="disabled"]') ) {
                isValid = true;
            } else {
                isValid = false;
            }
        });
        if (!isValid){
            alert("Please fill in all the required fields (highlighted in red)");
            console.log('derp');
        } else {
            console.log('done');
        }
        return isValid;

        var company = $('input[name=company-title]').val();
        var location = $('input[name=location-title]').val();
        var term = $('input[name=term]:checked').val();
        var closedate = $('input[name=vacancy-date]').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"/assets/inc/add-vacancy.php",
            data:"company="+company+"&location="+location+"&term="+term+"&closedate="+closedate,
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check whether all inputs are disabled use the [disabled-selector](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/)

```
var isValid = $("input[type=text]:not(:disabled)").length == 0;
if (!isValid) {
    alert("Please fill in all the required fields (highlighted in red)");
    console.log('derp');
    return isValid;
} else {
    console.log('done');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.each is a callback so it returns straightaway, you should change your each so that it does not return:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6483430/1823684